# Connecting and Retrieving from the SqlDatabase using SPA template

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm, single-page-application

I am trying to create a SPA model which is able to create, update, delete scheduled tasks in Visual Studio 2012 using MVC4 Hottowel SPA template. Here i have a  demo class which I need to use in creating database but unable to get 1)  the context of the database. 
2) how to configure the database in this project. I tried with creating connection using (LocalDb)\v11.0 sql server but its showing error that entity framework 6 or above is not supported with  this application.

```
public class JobDemo
{
  public string JobName { get; set; }
  public string JobDescription { get; set; }
  public string Frequency { get; set; }
  public bool JobStatus { get; set; }
  public bool JobIsActive { get; set; }
  public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

This is my class which I wanna use to create database of scheduled tasks/jobs and then query on them

```
public class DemoDb : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<JobDemo> Jobject { get; set; }

  public DemoDb() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
  {
  }
}
```

The class is creating the DbContext of my JobDemo Class. But after that i am unable to create database connection which use my class and use the following attributes defined in my JobDemo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the EF6 is not supported in SPA template, the SqlServer or SqlServerCompact Database can be used with HotTowel SPA template as they support the model and can be used with Breeze Api or Simple controllers with get and post methods can be used to retrieve and store data.